# Parsing a .tar file in C

Tags: c, tar

I'm working on extracting a tar file, but I'm running into an issue when reading blocks.  After my 6th read, despite seemingly only being less than half way through the tar file, all subsequent reads return empty buffers. Attached image shows contents of buffer after 6th read.
[image: tar error]
Above: Buffer contents on 6th read + where in the textfile this read seems to occur.
Below: Extracted contents of tar file.
[image: tar file contents]

My 1st read is the header file of the text file "testfile", and the 2nd read is the contents of that file. My 3rd read is the header for the folder "testdir".  My 4th read returns (I think) a header file for "testdir/._.DS_Store", but I don't know what that is; the 5th read is empty, and the 6th read returns a header file for "testdir/.DS_Store", I also don't know what this is. Looking at the text format of the .tar file, it seems there should be more information past this, but I can't seem to access it, and am therefor losing out on the nested folders/textfile.

Here is my code:

extract.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "shared.h"
#include "extract.h"

void extract(char* tarfile) {

    int in, out, i;
    Header header;


    in = safe_open(tarfile, O_RDONLY, 0);


    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        safe_read(in, &header, BLK_SIZE);

    }
}
```

## Note: I haven't started actually extracting, I'm just reading to the header buffer in order to see the information that I can read from the tar file. (hence the for loop)

shared.h:

```
#define BLK_SIZE 512

typedef struct posix_header {   /* byte offset */
    char name[NAME_LEN];          /*   0 */
    char mode[8];                 /* 100 */
    char uid[8];                  /* 108 */
    char gid[8];                  /* 116 */
    char size[12];                /* 124 */
    char mtime[12];               /* 136 */
    char chksum[CHKSUM_LEN];      /* 148 */
    char typeflag;                /* 156 */
    char linkname[NAME_LEN];      /* 157 */
    char magic[6];                /* 257 */
    char version[2];              /* 263 */
    char uname[32];               /* 265 */
    char gname[32];               /* 297 */
    char devmajor[8];             /* 329 */
    char devminor[8];             /* 337 */
    char prefix[PREFIX_LEN];      /* 345 */
    char extra_padding[12];       /* 500 */
} Header;           /* 512 */


int safe_open(const char* pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

shared.c:

```
void safe_read(int fd, void* buf, size_t count) {
    if (read(fd, buf, count) < 0) {
        perror(READ_ERR);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `BLK_SIZE`? You're going to read that many bytes each time you call `safe_read()`, not just the size of the header or file.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store for what `.DS_Store` is. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them for `._.` files.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about that I had omitted parts of the shared file for clarity and accidentally failed to include that #define, it is 512, I will update the main post.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks!  I had been looking at the wiki page for those files but I still wasn't really sure what to do with the block and/or if it was related to why I wasn't able to read in the data following it.

Comment: As far as tar is concerned they're just ordinary files, so it shouldn't affect your program.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing in `extract()`. Why are you looping 6 times, and overwriting the same `header` variable each time? If you want to extract a file, you need to read its header, then get the length from that, then read enough blocks to get that length.

Comment: @Barmar I haven't begun the actual extraction process, I was just doing some testing to see if I could access all the information within the .tar file I needed before I began to actually code the extraction.  I have it set to loop 6 times just to run through it with the debugger and check the contents of the header file after each read.

Comment: But sometimes you're reading file contents into the `header` structure.

Comment: tar isn't a text format, it's binary, so if you're just using printf to see what you read, you're going to see nothing if there happens to be a null byte before other bytes. what are you using to peek at the data you're reading in the header buffer, and what is the source to your `safe_read` function?

Comment: @MichaelSpeer safe_read is in the shared.c file (oops I included the incorrect function, let me fix that), I'm using CLion's debugging tool to inspect the values of header with a breakpoint inside the for loop, you can see the values at the bottom of the first image.

Comment: Use a library like [libtar](https://github.com/tklauser/libtar). BTW `read` can be a *partial* read so your `safe_read` is not that safe

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer, there were a huge number of empty blocks before I ran into the next directory so I just had iterate 24 times to find the nested directory...